# Why more number of duplicated data is saving in my excel sheet for my code?

Tags: web-scraping

Actually this code is generally used to scrape data from websites but the problem is more number of duplicated data is producing and saving in my excel sheet.

```
def extractor():
time.sleep(10)
souptree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
tburl = souptree.xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'theDataTable')]//tbody//tr//td[4]//a//@href")
for tbu in tburl:
    allurl = []
    allurl.append(urllib.parse.urljoin(siteurl, tbu))
    for tb in allurl:
        get_url = requests.get(tb)
        get_soup = html.fromstring(get_url.content)
        pattern = re.compile("^\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+$")
        name = get_soup.xpath('//td[@headers="contactName"]//text()')
        phone = get_soup.xpath('//td[@headers="contactPhone"]//text()')
        mail = get_soup.xpath('//td[@headers="contactEmail"]//a//text()')
        artitle = get_soup.xpath('//td[@headers="contactEmail"]//a//@href')
        artit = ([x for x in pattern.split(str(artitle)) if x][-1])
        title = artit[:-2]
        for (nam, pho, mai) in zip(name, phone, mail):
            fname = nam[9:]
            allmails.append(mai)
            allnames.append(fname)
            allphone.append(pho)
            alltitles.append(title)
            fullfile = pd.DataFrame({'Names': allnames, 'Mails': allmails, 'Title': alltitles, 'Phone Numbers': allphone})
            writer = ExcelWriter('G:\\Sheet_Name.xlsx')
            fullfile.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
            writer.save()
            print(fname, pho, mai, title, sep='\t')


while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    extractor()
    try:
        nextbutton()
    except (WebDriverException):
        driver.refresh()
    except(NoSuchElementException):
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.quit()
```

I want the output should not be duplicated but almost half and more number of data are duplicating each time i run the code.

Comment: what ```nextbutton()``` function does?

Comment: It will go to next page

Comment: Only one portion of code i write here....I just want to know why duplicated values are printing?

Comment: can you please share URL for scraping data, so that we can start debugging code. And best way to scrap the data in python to use ```BeutifulSoup```, as in your code you are using some ```driver``` which is a little confusing.

Comment: ScienceDirect.com: From this i have to collect data(like name,email and title of that journal) from  a specific keyword like(any medical term ex-cancer,oncology) with some specific time period(2018-2019) and have to store it in csv or excel sheets by using python libraries. Thank you again for your replay and can you suggest for any web-scraping materials by which i can be benefited more . Thank you again.